# Passing complex object as parameter to sub-stack

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I want to pass the output of a custom resource, which is an array of objects, as parameter to a sub-stack. An example of what I want to pass as parameter to the child stack is :

```
[
{"Role":"Role1","IdentifierType":"Prefix","Identifiers":"Bucket1"}
{"Role":"Role2","IdentifierType":"Prefix","Identifiers":"Bucket2"}
]
```

How do I pass this to the sub-stack? I tried declaring the parameter in the child stack as String, and later as CommaDelimitedList. Both the times, the stack gave an error: "Value of property Parameters must be an object with String (or simple type) properties"

Answer (score 2):

As I know until now, there is not way to pass complex objects as a result of of stack execution. Like the message say, the outputs need to be string or single types (integer and boolean in case of cloudformation).

Without more information is hard to help you with alternatives, but let's assume that your Custom Resource is based on lambda. And let's assume that you have control about the code of your Custom Resource. If this is the case you can:

1. Send the resource identification of your custom resource as a parameter for your nested stack;
2. Inside nested stack, invoke the lambda function again with the resourceId as a parameter;
3. Change the lambda code to check for a new parameter for the resourceId (inside the ResourceParameters, not inside the Common Resource Id sent by CloudFormation).
4. If the parameter is not empty (or not a defined value passed on the first invocation) respond with the old values (you must have a way to keep this values in some place or check then in runtime.);
5. Change the lambda code to do not take action in the update/deletion is case of invocation by the nested stack (with the resourceId parameter).

Again, is hard to think in alternatives without more info about your specific problem. But use this response as a food for thought.